# Floating point comparison not working on pandas groupby output

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, pandas-groupby

I am facing issues with pandas filtering of rows. I am trying to filter out team whose sum of weight is not equal to one.

```
dfteam
Team    Weight
A       0.2
A       0.5
A       0.2
A       0.1
B       0.5
B       0.25
B       0.25

dfteamtemp = dfteam.groupby(['Team'], as_index=False)['Weight'].sum()
dfweight = dfteamtemp[(dfteamtemp['Weight'].astype(float)!=1.0)]

dfweight
  Team  Weight
0  A     1.0
```

I am not sure about the reason for this output. I should get an empty dataframe but it is giving me Team A even thought the sum is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You are a victim of floating point inaccuracies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). The first value does not exactly add up to `1.0` -

```
df.groupby('Team').Weight.sum().iat[0]
0.99999999999999989
```

You can resolve this by using [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) instead -

```
np.isclose(df.groupby('Team').Weight.sum(), 1.0)
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And filter on this array. Or, as @ayhan suggested, use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) -

```
df.groupby('Team').filter(lambda x: not np.isclose(x['Weight'].sum(), 1))

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Team, Weight]
Index: []
```

Comment: I was also coming up with this one: `df.groupby('Team').filter(lambda x: not np.isclose(x['Weight'].sum(), 1))`

Comment: @ayhan Oh nice! using `filter`. Will you add an answer?

Comment: Actually I am getting 1.0 as the output of group.by line

Comment: I think the real issue is the floating point one so no need for an additional answer, edit into yours maybe?

Comment: @ArifAkhtar no, it appreas to be 1.0 but certainly not

Comment: @ArifAkhtar IPython must be rounding it up. But this is why you get that result.